# Get characters behind the dot in of a double

Tags: c#, .net, math, floating-point, string-formatting

I feel like this is a very noob question.. but I just can't get the right statement for it.

For display purposes, I want to split a `double` in two: the part before the dot and the first two digits after the dot. I need it as a `string`. Target language: C#.

E.g.:  `2345.1234`  becomes `"2345"` and `"12"`

I know how to get the part before the dot, that's simply:

```
Math.Floor(value).ToString()
```

...but what is the right way to get the part "behind the dot"?
There must be some nice way to do that in a simple way...

I can't think of anything else then:

```
Math.Round(100 * (value - Math.Floor(value))).ToString("00");
```

I'm sure there is a better way, but I just can't think of it. Anyone?

Comment: There certainly is a *better* way since the technique you've come up with is not *correct*. It fails if the double is negative, for instance.

Comment: That's right, but I forgot to mention that the value represents the price of a product, which is usually positive, unfortunately :)

Comment: If you are dealing with money, you should probably consider using the Decimal type.  That probably doesn't really help you get the fractional part of the number, but it will help keep your money straight!

Comment: Aha! Then you have an even bigger problem. Never ever use double to represent the price of a product; doubles have rounding error that is bad for prices. They are designed to represent physical quantities like length, not decimalized quantities like prices. Use the decimal data type, not the double data type, to represent a price.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions (regex) is probably you best bet, but using the mod operator may be another valuable solution...

```
  stuffToTheRight = value % 1
```

Cheers.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I didn't code for a few years and I knew there was this "something". I meant this good old mod operator :)

Comment: to get two digits use: `(int)(stuffToTheRight*100)`

Answer (score 4):

```
//
//Use the Fixed point formatting option.  You might have a bit more work to do 
//if you need to handle cases where "dot" is not the decimal separator.
//
string s = value.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var values = s.Split(".");
string v1 = values[0];
string v2 = values[1];
```

See this link for more about formatting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Here is some untested code that tries to take current culture into account:

```
//
//Use the Fixed point formatting option.
//
string s = value.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
var values = s.Split(CultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
string v1 = values[0];
string v2 = values[1];
```

Comment: +1 for taking regional settings into account, which is surprisingly rare.

Answer (score 0):

```
use regex ".[0-9][0-9]"
```

Comment: Be careful: this won't work if you don't set the culture for `ToString()` and the default culture has comma as a decimal separator.

Comment: Should be `"\.[0-9][0-9]" ` because "." matches any character.

Answer (score 0):

In one line it will be:
`string[] vals = value.ToString("f2").Split(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator.ToCharArray());`

`vals[0]` : before point.
`vals[1]` : after point.